# Call to a member function getRealPath() on array

Tags: laravel

I am trying to uploading multiple file .mp3 but unfortunately, I am facing an error **Call to a member function getRealPath() on array** but all data is inserting successfully except audio_file

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{          
  foreach ($request->title as $key => $value) {
      $audiodetail = new AudioDetail;
      $extension = Str::random(40) . ".mp3";
      $audiodetail->audio_file = Storage::disk('audiofile')->putFileAs('',$request->audio_file, $extension);
      $audiodetail->title = $value;
      $audiodetail->audio_id = $request->audio_id;
      $audiodetail->save();
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add the snippet of your blade form.

Comment: Where are you using `getRealpath()`? There is no mention of that in your code snippet

Comment: thanks to everyone just i need to pass key $request->audio_file[$key] it's working